# Enable autocomplete in archlinux adb shell

Tags: shell, android, arch-linux, autocomplete

In archlinux, when using the command `adb shell` provided by the package `android-tools` to obtain a shell on an Android device, the auto-completion using <kbd>Tab</kbd> is not working.

Everything else is working fine but the auto-completion. Do you know what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no problem, it is just how it works (it won't autocomplete). There are a few tricks to make adb autocomplete its own commands (see [here](http://www.jessechen.net/blog/protip-bash-autocomplete-for-android-adb/)), but no way of which I am aware of autocompleting file paths and so on.

Comment: It is autocompleting also the paths on Ubuntu

Comment: It is? I am using 14.04 and it has never autocompleted (nor for anyone else in my office).